# jQuery retrieve only textboxes that have a non-empty value

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, how do I get only the textboxes that have a non-empty value?

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="i1" value="" />
<input type="text" id="i2" value="bla bla" />
<textarea id="i3">more bla bla</textarea>
<input type="text" id="i4" value="" />
```

How do I write a query that can get me only the inputs i2 and i3? (in one shot, I'm trying to avoid a "for" loop)

Thanks!

Comment: There is no attribute as `val` in HTML. There is `value` for input, but not for textarea.

Comment: Are we talking about empty `value` **attributes** or empty input fields in general (i.e. fields that are empty *after* the user had the possibility to insert data)?

Comment: @KARAZI: I'm pretty sure there is a value for textareas

Comment: @user828584: [No, there is not](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.7). Yes, the [corresponding DOM element has a `value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTextareaElement), but there is no such HTML attribute.

Comment: @user828584: I don't really think so: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-TEXTAREA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your HTML should actually look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="i1" value="">
<input type="text" id="i2" value="bla bla">
<textarea id="i3">more bla bla</textarea>
<input type="text" id="i4" value="">
```

I assume most browsers will default to `type="text"` for input fields if it's not specified, but I don't think you can count on them to figure out that `val` means `value`. Finally, textarea text has to go between the `<textarea>` tags.

On to your question, though. This line will do what you want:

```
$('input[type="text"], textarea').filter(function() { return $(this).val(); });
```

You can use jQuery's [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function, which loops through an array and keeps only the values that satisfy (return a truthy value from) the function you pass to `$.grep`. In this case the array that you're passing is an array of jQuery objects that match the `$('input[type="text"], textarea')` selector, i.e. text fields and textareas. The function you're passing to select the elements that you want simply returns the value of the text box or textarea. If it's blank then the return value is falsy and the node is excluded, and if it's any non-blank string then the return value is truthy and the node is included.

Comment: you're right about the HTML, I've fixed that in my question. Your solution is totally nice and clean :). Thanks!

Comment: The problem with `$.grep` here is that it returns an array, not a jQuery object. Using `.filter()` would make more sense. And yes, the default type of input fields is `text`.

Answer (score 9):

This would do the job:

```
var $nonEmptyItems = $("input,textarea").filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() != "";
});
```

Comment: yep, that is wat I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the value attribute then this could be done:

```
$('input[value!=""], textarea[value!=""]')
```

Comment: `textarea`s don't have a `value` attribute anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute selector with a != evaluation:

```
$("input[value!='')")
```